# Change href value with JS from select box

Tags: javascript, html

I have this select box that gets its data from my DB.
What I want to do is add Edit and Delete buttons next to my select box that will do the respective actions on the current selected option.

So I added two buttons that direct to php scripts that do all this work.
My problem is with JavaScript where I need to update the  elements of the buttons.

However my JS function doesn't work.
It appears that it isn't even fired.

http://jsfiddle.net/y5g42/33/

HTML:

```
<select name='selectHotel' onChange='updateButtons(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text)'>
    <option value="volvo.php">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab.php">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes.php">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi.php">Audi</option>
</select>
<a href='' id='editButton'><button>Edit</button></a>
<a href='' id='deleteButton'><button>Delete</button></a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function updateButtons(var) {
    element = document.getElementById('editButton');
    element.href = var;
}​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems with your logic and the fiddle itself.

Best way without using JavaScript library is to attach the `onchange` handler in the `onload` of the window and handle everything there:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var oDDL = document.getElementById("selectHotel");

    oDDL.onchange = function updateButtons() {
        var oLink = document.getElementById('editButton');    
        oLink.href = oDDL.value;
    };

    oDDL.onchange();
};
```

To have it work, add `id="selectHotel"` to the `<select>` element and remove the inline `onchange` from it.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5g42/45/).

In your initial fiddle you didn't choose proper framework properties.

Note that I am calling the `onchange` manually one time to reflect the selected value, otherwise clicking the button before selecting other value won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `var` as variable name - `var` is javascripts reserved word.

Answer (score 1):

jsFiddle's `onLoad` option wraps your code in a callback function.
Therefore, your function definition isn't visible outside the code.

You need to select `No Wrap` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You just passed value rather than text on `onchange` function

```
  onChange='updateButtons(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)'
```

You can try something like this :

```
 window.updateButtons = function(value) {

     element = document.getElementById('editButton');
     var url = window.location.href;
     element.href = url + value;
     console.log(element.href);  
}
```

**See Demo**  : http://jsfiddle.net/y5g42/46/